# Multiple level iteration inside folder to find all the text files on Windows

Tags: perl

I have a scenario where I need to loop through multiple level directories to find text files.

Say, I start from the folder `C:\A` and then I want to read all the text files inside it. But they are not placed at same level.

Some text files are arranged at `C:\A\A1\sample1.txt`

Some as `C:\A\sample2.txt`

Some as `C:\A\A2\A3\sample.txt`

I am able to loop inside the folder A which returns me `A1` and `A2`, but I wanted to know is there a way it would iterate automatically to every level and return me the text files along with its path.
ance!

Comment: show the code you have tried

Comment: I wrote for this:
opendir(DH,$ISF_dir);
my @files = readdir(DH);
closedir(DH);

foreach my $file (@files)
{
  next if($file =~ /^\.$/);
  next if($file =~ /^\.\.$/);
  print "$file\n";
  
  if (-d $file){                  # is this a directory?
               print "\n1\n";
          }
}

But it was never detecting the folders as directories.

Comment: put it in the post, not a comment

Answer (score 0):

Use the `File::Find` module to do it.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Find 'find';

my @files;

find(sub {
    push @files, $File::Find::name if -f and /\.txt$/i;
}, 'C:\A');

print "$_\n" for @files;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule -> file() 
                             -> name('sample*.txt')
                             -> in ( 'C:\\A' );

foreach my $file ( @files ) {
   print "Found: $file\n";
   #process it here. 
}
```